# Can validate and converter be combined in jsViews data-link?

Tags: jsviews

I can ensure data exists in an input element by including *validate* and *required* in jsViews' data-link attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" data-link="{validate activityCode required=true}">
```

And by following [Boris Moore's example](http://borismoore.github.io/jsviews/demos/jQueryConfDemosOct2011/13_converters.html) I can ensure the data *returned* to the model is cast as an integer instead of input's default type of string:

```
$.views.converters({
    toInt: function(value) {
        return parseInt(value);  // simple example, without error checking
    }
});

<input type="text" data-link="{:activityCode:toInt}">
```

Where I'm having a problem is combining both validation and converter. Nothing binds to the input element using this:

```
<input type="text" data-link="{validate activityCode:toInt required=true}">
```

Does anyone know of syntax that allows both validation and *convertBack* functionality to exist in the same data-link attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax `convert=...` `convertBack=...` on any tag.

See [two-way binding - convert and convertBack](http://www.jsviews.com/#link2way@converters) and [using converters with other tags](http://www.jsviews.com/#converters@othertags). (The second docs reference is for JsRender, so concerns convert only. But if using JsViews data-linking, then `convertBack=...` works in just the same way.)

[Search for "convertBack="](http://www.jsviews.com/#search?s=convertback%3D) and you'll find some examples, including [this](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/form-els/converters) with radiogroup and [this one](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/validate/simple) with validate.

Comment: Per Boris' direction, using tag syntax rather than `:` solved my problem. The correct syntax is `<input type="text" data-link="{validate activityCode convertBack=toInt required=true}">`